# Facebook comments don't appear in Backbonejs views

Tags: facebook, backbone.js, facebook-like

I'm using Backbonejs for my app and I'm trying to add Facebook comments and like/send buttons to some of my views. I'm instantiating the JavaScript SDK before instantiating the Router object, like this :

```
// main.js  
require([ "Router" ], function (Router) {

// Facebook authentication
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '302210766529054', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

   // If the user has auth'd the app, instantiate the router object.
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                 // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                FB.api('/me', function(me){
                    if (me.username) {
                        window.currentUser = me;
                        $('#username').html(window.currentUser.name);
                        new Router();
                        Backbone.history.start();
                    }
                });
            }
    });

}
```

});

I can easily use the `windows.currentUser` variable in any of the views called by the Router. However, when I add

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mywebsite/i/#items/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

to one the templates called by a view in the router, the comments (nor the like/send) div doesn't appear. When I add it to one of the static elements of the index.html file, it works fine.

Am I missing anything here?

***EDIT***

Here is my router and views code as it was before i post the question.

```
router.js
define(
[
'models/song',
'models/user',
'models/spotlight',
'models/user-playlist',
'views/spotlight-view',
'views/playlist-view',
'views/single-playlist-view',
],
function(Song, User, SpotlightModel,UserPlaylist, SpotlightView, PlaylistView, SinglePlaylistView){
    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            window.songQue = new Array();

        },
        routes:{
            '': 'index',
            'spotlight': 'index',
            'playlists': 'allPlaylist',
            'playlists/:id':'onePlaylist',
        },

        index: function(){
            var spotlight = new SpotlightModel({id:1});
            var spotlightView = new SpotlightView({spotlight: spotlight});
            spotlight.fetch();
            $('.content').html(spotlightView.el);
        },

        allPlaylist: function(){
            $('.content').html('');
            var user = new User({id:window.currentUser.id});
            /*
             * once user details are fetched from the server,
             * loop through the arrays of their playlists and
             * render them in the template.
             */

            user.bind('change', function(){
                console.log(this);
                for(var i=0; i<this.get('objects')[0].playlists.length; i++){
                var playlistView = new PlaylistView({
                    playlist: user.get('objects')[0].playlists[i],
                    user: this.get('objects')[0]
                });
                $('.content').prepend(playlistView.el);
            }

            });
        },

        onePlaylist: function(playlist_id){
            var userPlaylist = new UserPlaylist({id:playlist_id});
            var singlePlaylistView = new SinglePlaylistView({playlist: userPlaylist});
            $('.content').html(singlePlaylistView.el);

        }
    });
}
   );



// single-playlist-view.js
define(
[
    'text!templates/single-playlist/single-playlist.html',
    'text!templates/single-playlist/single-playlist-details.html',
    'text!templates/playlist/song-row.html',
],
function(SinglePlaylistTemplate, SinglePlaylistDetailsTemplate, SongRowTemplate){
    return Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize:function(options){

            this.playlistTemplate = _.template(SinglePlaylistTemplate);
            this.playlistDetailsTemplate = _.template(SinglePlaylistDetailsTemplate);
            this.songRowTemplate = _.template(SongRowTemplate);
            this.playlist = options.playlist;

            $(this.el).prepend(this.playlistTemplate);
            this.playlist.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.playlist.fetch();


        },

        render:function(){
            this.renderSongs();
            this.renderDetails();

        },

        renderSongs: function(){
            // Put the size of songs in a variable 
            var size = this.playlist.get('objects')[0].songs.length;
            // Extra loop just for the sake of filling the page.
            for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
                for(var i=0; i<size; i++){

                this.$("#song-row").prepend(this.songRowTemplate({
                    song: this.playlist.get('objects')[0].songs[i]
                }));
            }
            }
        },

        renderDetails: function(){
            this.$('.single-playlist-details').prepend(this.playlistDetailsTemplate({
                playlist: this.playlist,
                thumbnail: this.playlist.get('objects')[0].songs[0].song_thumbnail,
                total:this.playlist.get('objects')[0].songs.length,
            }));
        }

    });
}
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backbone views will are being rendered after the Facebook API Call - at the stage when you make the Facebook call the element does not exist.

You really want to do the Facebook call inside your Router in the route for the page you want to display the facebook API results.

If its something that you want to display on every page - e.g. Username/Profile pic consider putting the code in a separate function eg initUserInfoView()  and then call it from each route where you want to display the info.

To be honest this stuff actually belongs in your View - the router should initialize and render the view, and the view is responsible for fetching from Facebook and displaying

Comment: This works very well BUT only when I go to the url directly. If the comments should appear in the page `http://mywebsite.com/i/#items` and I go to `http://mywebsite.com/` and click on a link that leads me to the page where I should see the comments, the comments are hidden again.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry...  I'm thinking that the initialize method is called before each route, but its not.  Its called when the router.Start is called. That's why it doesn't work.  You'll do the call from every route - although as I mentioned in the revised answer, this stuff (displaying data on a view) really belongs in a Backbone.View

Comment: Well, even that I use initialize method in every view, it doesn't work i unless i hit the refresh button

Comment: You'll need to post the code for your router and views to help you more

Comment: I updated the original post. I posted the view and the router code before I edit it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of @reach4thelasers
I created a CommentsView that loads the comments from Facebook, and I call it in every view where I need the comments. I simply call the `FB.init` in the `initialize` function of the CommentsView
So the code looks something like this:

```
initialize: function(){
            FB.init({
                    appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
                    channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
                    status     : true, // check login status
                    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            this.commentsTemplate = _.template(CommentsTemplate);
                $(this.el).html(this.commentsTemplate({
                    comments_url: window.location.href
                }));
        }
```

Comment: You should mark the answer that helped you, not rewrite the answer and mark your own

Comment: I thought I should mark the solution to the problem. I stated that I solved it with your help anyways ;)